# Linq To CRM IQueryable Issue

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, crm

I'm attempting to dynamically filter the results of a query in Linq-To-CRM.

Basically i have a standard query and based on certain criteria I then want to be able to add certain filters to this. I am however getting this error...
**The method 'Where' cannot follow the method 'Select' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported methods.**

A simplified sample of my code is shown below. Anyone know if this can be done using linq-to-sql?
I potentially have 5 or 6 separate filters that I may or may not have to add dynamically. I can of course define separate queries for all of the possible combinations of the filters but this seems like overkill & I want to avoid this if at all possible.

```
IQueryable<CourseProduct> coursesVar =
(
    from a in context.CreateQuery("vs_course")
    join b in context.CreateQuery("product") on a["vs_product"] equals b["productid"]
    join c in context.CreateQuery("productpricelevel") on b["productid"] equals c["productid"]
    join d in context.CreateQuery("vs_coursetype") on a["vs_coursetype"] equals d["vs_coursetypeid"]
    join e in context.CreateQuery("vs_coursearea") on a["vs_coursearea"] equals e["vs_courseareaid"]
    where a["vs_product"] != null // ensure product is set
    && a["vs_coursetype"] != null
    && a["vs_coursearea"] != null
    && a["vs_price"] != null
    where b["price"] != null
    where c["pricelevelid"] != null
    && (Guid)c["pricelevelid"] == pricelistId // ensure price list is set (and matches the correct pricelist)
    && c["amount"] != null
    select new CourseProduct
    {
        CourseId = (Guid)a["vs_courseid"],
        CourseCode = !a.Contains("vs_code") ? string.Empty : (string)a["vs_code"],
        CourseName = !a.Contains("vs_name") ? string.Empty : (string)a["vs_name"],
        CourseType = !a.Contains("vs_coursetype") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)a["vs_coursetype"]).Name,
        CoursePrice = !a.Contains("vs_price") ? -997 : ((Money)a["vs_price"]).Value,
        ProductPrice = !b.Contains("price") ? -996 : ((Money)b["price"]).Value,
        PricelistItemPrice = !c.Contains("amount") ? -995 : ((Money)c["amount"]).Value,
        CurrencySymbol = currencySymbol,
        ActualType = !d.Contains("vs_type") ? -999 : ((OptionSetValue)d["vs_type"]).Value,
        CourseTypeId = (Guid)d["vs_coursetypeid"],
        CourseAreaId = (Guid)e["vs_courseareaid"],
        CourseTypeCode = !d.Contains("vs_code") ? string.Empty : (string)d["vs_code"],
        CourseAreaCode = !e.Contains("vs_code") ? string.Empty : (string)e["vs_code"]
    }
);

// now try and add some filters dynamically
coursesVar = coursesVar.Where(i => i.CourseCode == "X");
coursesVar = coursesVar.Where(i => i.CourseAreaCode == "Y");

var finalList = coursesVar.ToList(); // this line throws the error
```

Comment: Dont set as IQueryable, set as List and in the end of the query, make a cast ToList()

Comment: But then it doesn't get executed as a single query surely?
This would result in the entire result set being returned and I would then be filtering on the entire set subsequently - which is what I am trying to avoid by using IQueryable in the first place.

Comment: I think the query looks like "from ... where... select new... where... where .. toList()". Linq-Crm is very strict and you only can follow the structure "from - where - select". Why you don't add the last 2 wheres in the first query?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense it is not supported. Otherwise linq-2-sql has to be so smart it can translate your entire code in the `select new {}` with the extra filters and back to SQL and perform that in the database. That would be a killer feature...

So you should add your Where before the select new{}

Something like

```
from a in context.CreateQuery("vs_course")
<and the rest of your complex join>
```

And redo do the filters first

```
// now try and add some filters dynamically
coursesVar = coursesVar.Where(|rephrase in terms of the Original query|}
```

Finally

```
Select new
```

This obviously has the disadvantage that the 'clean' code of the dynamic filters needs to be phrased more in the Original query style.

The alternative is to materialize before adding the filters. That would depend on ration between the number of rows begin returned before/after the filter.